# Overcome MPEG 2 TS Link Buildup Latency

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, mpeg2-ts

I have built a TS audio video link. I send encoded raw audio and video from one computer to another using TS over Ethernet. I am using FFMPEG libraries for this. Everything works fine except there is a latency build up with time.

When i play the raw video content at both encode and decoder ends, initially there is very little visible latency(less than a second). But when time increases the difference of the two videos slowly increase. I am playing the received video using a fixed frame rate.

As i have understood it is possible to us the PCR value to overcome this latency build up problem but it is not clear to me how to use that value..

Can someone kindly tell me how to use the PCR value of a TS stream to avoid latency build up?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't get when the TS is built: you say you have "raw" video on both encoder and decoder ends ? Is the latency only between the 2 videos or is audio out of sync too ?